# csv reader quotes and line separating

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file generated with the following writer settings:

```py
csv.writer(buffer, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

Quoted values with default line separating with `\r\n`.

Now I tried to read this csv from the flask request:

```py
from flask import request

file = request.files['file']
content = file.read().decode('utf8')
reader = csv.reader(content, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

for row in list(reader)[:20]:
    print(row)
```

`content` looks like this:
`'\r\n"id";"name"...`

But instead of

```
[]
[]
['id', 'name', ...]
```

I got this:

```
[]
[]
['id']
['', '']
['name']
['', '']
```

I've tried all quoting options, but still can`t understand why the reader puts these empty fields and unable to get the right representation of the rows. Any suggestions?

Comment: Show a sample of the file contents.

Comment: `csv.reader(content, ...)` should be `csv.reader(file, ...)`

Comment: @Barmar, no, werkzeug uses io.BytesIO or tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile as a buffer, they both return bytes while reading, and csv.reader accepts only strings, not bytes.

Comment: Then you need to split it into lines, e.g. `content = file.read().decode('utf8').split('\r\n')`. `csv.reader` expects the argument to be an iterator that returns lines, not a single string.

Comment: @Barmar, and it worked! Thanks.